# Java change variable without using getter and setter

Tags: java

I have these four classes and I want to change the variable used in the for loop

I mainly want to change curLine variable from Comment.getComment method

URLReader.java

```
public class URLReader {
    ParseHTML ParseHTML = new ParseHTML();
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URLReader URLReader = new URLReader();
        URLReader.ParseHTML.parseHTML();

        }

}
```

ParseHTML.java

```
public class ParseHTML {
    int curLine = 0;
    Comment Comment = new Comment();
    CharacterAndLine CharacterAndLine = new CharacterAndLine();

    public void parseHTML() {
        for (curLine = curLine; curLine < 100; curLine++) {
            curLine = CharacterAndLine.getCurrentLine()+curLine;
            System.out.println(curLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment.java

```
public class Comment {
    CharacterAndLine CharacterAndLine = new CharacterAndLine();
    public void getComment() {
        CharacterAndLine.setCurrentLine(50);
    }

}
```

CharacterAndLine.java

```
public class CharacterAndLine {
    int currentLine;

    public int getCurrentLine() {
        return currentLine;
    }
    public void setCurrentLine(int newCurrentLine) {
        currentLine = newCurrentLine;
    }
}
```

I need someway to change curLine variable if not getter and setter.

Comment: Where are `i` and `x` declared? Why are you using (what looks like) instance fields as loop counters? Loop variables are _almost always_ temporary and not shared.

Comment: Please try to rewrite this question to better explain what you're trying to do.  In its present form, this question is not really understandable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the error you're having is because whenever you have a Coment, you create a ParseHTML, which then creates its own Comment, which then creates its own ParseHTML ad infinitum.

The question you have (unrelated) is about changing the loop counter in Comment.getComment(). You cannot do this unless it is in the scope of getComment() and even if you could it would be bad practice to do so, for numerous reasons, including that variables used in a loop should be local, getComment() should not have side-effects, and should not be connected to that loop. The body of the loop should change the variables instead of getComment(). You can check the Comment returned by it in order to determine inside the loop whether to change i or x.